# How to change the default "www directory" for wampserver

Tags: wampserver

All my websites are located in `D:/Documents/websites` directory. I already managed to point `http://localhost/` to that folder based on this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRNe9EnNJOs).

But what I also want is whenever I click on "www directory" from the wampserver panel it opens up `D:/Documents/websites` directory instead of `C:/wamp/www` which is the default one.

[image]

How do I achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First make a backup of `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl` as mistakes in here can make wampmanager unstartable.

Now edit `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl` using a decent editor and not `notepad`

Find this line, its line 138 approx.

> Type: item; Caption: "${w_wwwDirectory}"; Action: shellexecute; FileName: "${wwwDir}"; Glyph: 2

Copy/Paste that line below itself and then change it to be something like this

> Type: item; Caption: "My Sites"; Action: shellexecute; FileName: "d:/Documents/Websites"; Glyph: 2

Save the file.

Now either start WAMPServer or if it was actually already running refresh the menus by doing :-

> rightclick on wampmanager icon -> refresh

You should now see your new menu.

If you want you could now go back and delete the original line that creates the `www directory` menu item.