# How to Change the www root directory on WampServer 2.5

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

My need is to change the default sites directory of wamp from say "c:\wamp\www" to say "d:\sites".
Right now my projects in "d:\sites" do not show in the project list:

[image]

I found a few past answers like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28477298/how-to-change-the-default-www-directory-for-wampserver) and [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43522/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver) one which I think are not applicable to WampServer 2.5 (anyway, it did not work for me).

I also found this [procedure](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685) in the documentation, but it seems far too complex for what I need.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

Comment: Just change the path in the configuration file. Then restart the http server process.

Comment: The best way to do this is to create Virtual Hosts. You can have many VHOSTS in one Apache instance, one for each project, and the location of each project can be different and be located almost anywhere. [See this post for how to setup Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Comment: Thanks @RiggsFolly (also for correcting my typo). " Virtual Hosts" is explained in one of the links I posted. I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: Its not actually complicated. Once you have the first working its just a copy/paste for every new project

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In newer version of wamp, changing DocumentRoot in httpd.conf did not change DOCUMENT_ROOT. Even after restarting, it stayed as "c:/wamp64/www/".

Instead, the DocumentRoot is set in this file:

> ```
>   c:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.18\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
> ```

To change the localhost directory, change these to your path:

> ```
>       DocumentRoot c:/www
>       <Directory  "c:/www/">
> ```

Comment: And now I have to copy some stuff like wamp languages and wamp themes.... How these guys thought I will change the root?

Answer (score 8):

The thing you wanna do is little bit tricky.To do the thing you want just follow following steps:

**1**
Open file `C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache*.*.*\conf\httpd.conf`

**2**
Find following lines :

```
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
```

**3**
Modify  them to change your root directory  `/*In my case i want my "C:\" drive as root*/` so i do this :

```
DocumentRoot "c:/"
<Directory "c:/">
```

**4**
Now go to `c:\wamp\www` find `index.php` and copy it,and pest into your new root `/*In my case i want my "C:\" drive as root*/`

**5**
Now open that `index.php` and find the following lines:

```
$wampConfFile = '../wampmanager.conf';
$aliasDir = '../alias/';
```

**6**
Now just modify them relative to your root `/*In my case i want my "C:\" drive as root*/` so i write:

```
$wampConfFile = './wamp/wampmanager.conf';
$aliasDir = './wamp/alias/';
```

Now it will show the default wamp opening page which is shown in the picture!

Comment: Thanks @G4uKu3_Gaurav. The edit you propose is documented in one of the links I posted. It will indeed make Apache server to start at the desired folder, but it will not show the default wamp opening page which is show in the picture I posted.  Copying index.php from the default www folder to the desired folder, did not solve it.

Comment: @Ofer Yuval I hava modified my Answer and it's doing the thing you wanna do!

Comment: Thanks @G4uKu3_Gaurav. It is very similar to what I was trying to do, but something is not working. The new index.php has  $server_dir = "../";   AND   $aliasDir = $server_dir.'alias/';    AND  $wampConfFile = $server_dir.'wampmanager.conf';      so I treid to change  server_dir to the new folder : $server_dir = "D:/Program Files/wamp/";    but  WAMP icon remains yellow, and running localhost comes up with "This webpage is not available"

Comment: I am using craft cms and there already is an index.php file where I want to point the www folder of wamp...what do i do?

Answer (score 7):

1. Search the **httpd.conf** file

[image]

2. Change the **DocumentRoot** and  Path with the one that you want:

[image]

3. Search the **httpd-vhosts.conf** file

[image]

4. Change the **DocumentRoot** and  Path with the one that you want:

[image]

5. Restart All services

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The best thing about the apache is that it will tell you where it gets an error while trying to load configuration files.
on `WampServer 3.2.0`, I had to make change to few files.

1. Change it in your virtual hosts file
   **{installDirectory}\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

   `ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot "D:\Projects\ApacheWWW"
   <Directory "D:\Projects\ApacheWWW/">`
2. Change it in your **index.php** from `www` folder

   `$server_dir = "C:/wamp64/";`
3. In `scripts/config.inc.php` line 13
   `$configurationFile = 'C:/wamp64/wampmanager.conf';`

Comment: Thanks! So far, all is working (PHP and HTML) with just doing your step 1. I'll try 2 and 3 if I run into issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to apache httpd

   C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf
2. Open httpd
3. Find **DocumentRoot** in that file
4. Change the path
5. Find the directory tag
6. Change to *Allow from all* from *Deny from all* in Directory tag

   ```
   <Directory />
     Options FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
7. Save & exit
8. Restart wamp services

Answer (score -1):

Edit the path in below file then restart wamp server
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks @ajs. Please see the comment on G4uKu3_Gaurav 's answer.