# WAMP Server can not direct to the home page

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver

Recently I installed wamp server to set up a server environment in a Windows machine. Everything works great, but I have a little problem.
If I am working on a project named `test`, I can access the project by going to `http://localhost/test`.
When I create a link to go to the root(`test`): `<a href="/">Go to the root test</a>`, I am directed to `http://localhost` instead of  `http://localhost/test`.

Is there any way for me to solve this problem ?

Thank you for providing your help.

Comment: point your test folder as your root document http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635648/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver-2-5

Comment: You need to create a Virtual Host for each of your projects. Remember as you have it setup localhost points to `C:\wamp\www` and not `C:\wamp\www\test` Theis [will explain the situation and the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm oversimplifying, but the root is just localhost and a link specified as `href="/"` will always take you there. To link to the localhost/test directory, *which is not your root directory* it's `href="/test"`

Comment: WHile this is an answer. If you use this approach, when you come to move your site to a live environment you will have to recode