# Run php applications

Tags: php

I have Wamp installed in a computer running Windows and, obviously, if I have a php project inside c:wamp64/www it works fine

My question is whether it is possible to store php projects in another path (for example, My Documents/NetbeansProyects/Name) and run them from there.

Thank you

Comment: https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/running-php-scripts-outside-of-documentroot

Comment: You could specify a virtual host with a different root

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Change the www root directory on WampServer 2.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635648/how-to-change-the-www-root-directory-on-wampserver-2-5)